# Bootstrap carousel does not display images on the same line

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a carousel with `bootstrap`, and the aim is to have 5 images shown and every time it slides, it advances of 1.

The issue I am actually having at the moment, is that the elements are not aligned together but they

[Here](http://www.bootply.com/IHEqF0e8ux) you can find the complete code

Someone know how to fix the issue and put all the elements on the same line? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the margin on this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2" style="margin-right: 15%">
```

So, it's just:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
```

As bootstrap adds its own margins which you are overwriting?

Comment: Yeah that's a good solution, but apparently if you add an image then it splits the elements on another line due to its width. That's why I have added the `margin-right` tag to show you the issue.

Comment: You can add 'img-responsive' as a class on your images, so it would be <img src="img" title="D" class='img-responsive'> - that way your images will resize to the col-xs-2 box.....

Answer (score 0):

The corect answer is to add `<div class="row">` before your columns. Look at the css and you will understand why:

```
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2,.col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 1px;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right: 15px;
```

}

That is the default Boostrap css try making your code like that.

Also the `.item` container should contain the element you want in a single slide. If you want 3 images in slide, you should put them in a single `.item` container

Comment: Do you mean that I have to add `.row` before every `.item`? Concerning the second part of your question, the order of the images works since only one has to advance...

Comment: If you use `.col-...` you should always have a `.row` before them, as you can see, the `.row` class pulls them into place. See [Boostrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro)

Comment: I have tried to insert a `.row` before each `.col-...`, but then all the elements are stacked on the same column. Could you try to edit the bootply link and show me what you mean? Thanks a lot!